# I have a list of names and i am trying to extract first name and last name from the list in python

Tags: python, regex, list, dictionary, split

Below is the code I am working on, I am not able to extract the first names and last names from the names list. The code keeps giving me error too many values to unpack may be because for example this name ELSWOCK Rick Jr is having first middle and last name. Here Rick Jr should be the first name and Elswock as last name.

```
names=[' HE XF, Wei W, Liu ZZ, Shen XL',' STARK LE, AARON FIN, LEO DE CAP, ADAM FORTH, KARAN SINGH',' ELSWICK RICK Jr, ASTO FON, SAM MARLON, KIM ZENG']
names1 = []
for l1 in names:
    names1.append(l1.split(',')) #To split the line based on commas
first_names=[]
last_names=[]
for line in names1:
    last,first= line[0][:].split()
    first_names.append(first)
    last_names.append(last)
```

Results in this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "", line 10, in 
>   last,first= line[0][:].split()
>
> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

The output I am expecting would be like this:

```
first_names=[ 'XF, W, ZZ, XL', 'LE, FIN, CAP, FORTH, SINGH', 'RICK Jr, FON, MARLON, ZENG' ]
last_names=[' HE, Wei, Liu, Shen',' STARK, AARON, LEO DE, ADAM, KARAN',' ELSWICK, ASTO, SAM, KIM']
```

Comment: `LEO DE CAP` will give you `LEO`, `DE` and `CAP` in `line[0][:].split()`. You need to specify where you want to split, which is not trivial with name like this.

Comment: Should the input be `names=[' HE XF, Wei W, Liu ZZ, Shen XL',' STARK LE, AARON FIN, LEO DE CAP, ADAM FORTH, KARAN SINGH',' ELSWICK RICK Jr, ASTO FON, SAM MARLON, KIM ZENG']` or `names=[' HE XF, Wei W, Liu ZZ, Shen XL STARK LE, AARON FIN, LEO DE CAP, ADAM FORTH, KARAN SINGH , ELSWICK RICK Jr, ASTO FON, SAM MARLON, KIM ZENG']` - Why are there extra ',' in your example?

Comment: Use `(?<fn>\b[A-Z]+\b(?: +[A-Z]*[a-z]+[a-zA-Z]*)?(?=,|$))` for first names. Extract & replace them from original string. Then clean the remaining data using `^ | (?=,)` replace with empty string.

Comment: Also why is `LEO DE` a last name while you mentioned `Elswick Rick Jr` should be handled differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited to fit OP's format requirements:

```
names=[' HE XF, Wei W, Liu ZZ, Shen XL',' STARK LE, AARON FIN, LEO DE CAP, ADAM FORTH, KARAN SINGH',' ELSWICK RICK Jr, ASTO FON, SAM MARLON, KIM ZENG']
names1 = []
for l1 in names:
    names1.append(l1.split(','))
first_names=[]
last_names=[]

for sub_list in names1:
  temp_sub_firsts ="" 
  temp_sub_lasts ="" 
  for full_name in sub_list:
    full_name_split = full_name.split(' ')
    full_name_split.pop(0)
    temp_sub_lasts += full_name_split.pop(0)
    if full_name != sub_list[-1]:
      temp_sub_lasts += ', '
    temp_first = ""
    for sub_first in full_name_split:
      temp_first += sub_first + ' '
    temp_sub_firsts += temp_first
    if full_name != sub_list[-1]:
      temp_sub_firsts += ', '
  first_names.append(temp_sub_firsts)
  last_names.append(temp_sub_lasts)
print(first_names)
print(last_names)
```

Outputs:

`first_names[]=`

`['XF , W , ZZ , XL ', 'LE , FIN , DE CAP , FORTH , SINGH ', 'RICK Jr , FON , MARLON , ZENG ']`

`last_names[]=`

`['HE, Wei, Liu, Shen', 'STARK, AARON, LEO, ADAM, KARAN', 'ELSWICK, ASTO, SAM, KIM']`

Comment: Hello Nathan thanks for respose, yes it works but i want answer to be with proper indexing that is for example the last name list will be: [' HE', ' Wei ', ' Liu ', ' Shen '] in list index 0 and the last name list index 1 would be ['STARK', 'AARON', 'LEO', 'ADAM', 'KARAN'] and index 3 will have  ['ELSWICK', 'ASTO', 'SAM', 'KIM'] and similarly for first names. thank you

Comment: Yes the input leads with space it is a dummy list i have created. But the actual list is having 48 lines which and it has a space in it.

Comment: I've edited the answer to (hopefully) fit these requirements - There is still some cleaning up to do (removing extra/uneeded spaces etc.) but this should be enough to get you down the right path - good luck :)

Comment: Awesome. This edited code works perfectly fine with my list, Thanks a lot. Much appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this too

```
names=[' HE XF, Wei W, Liu ZZ, Shen XL',' STARK LE, AARON FIN, LEO DE CAP, ADAM FORTH, KARAN SINGH',' ELSWICK RICK Jr, ASTO FON, SAM MARLON, KIM ZENG']
reg1=re.compile(r"\w+(?<!,)\s(?=(?!Jr)[\w ]+,?)")
reg2=re.compile(r'(?<!,)\s(?:(?!Jr|DE)[\w ]+(?=,?))')
first_names=[reg1.sub("",m.strip()) for m in names]
last_names=[reg2.sub("",m.strip()) for m in names]
print("{}\n{}".format(first_names,last_names))
```

Output is

```
['XF, W, ZZ, XL', 'LE, FIN, CAP, FORTH, SINGH', 'RICK Jr, FON, MARLON, ZENG']
['HE, Wei, Liu, Shen', 'STARK, AARON, LEO DE, ADAM, KARAN', 'ELSWICK, ASTO, SAM, KIM']
```